# ¿Como convertir String rest = "1,2,3"; en un array de enteros en JAVA?

Tags: java

buena noche!

Tengo tres String `String cosa1 = request.getParameter("cosa1").toString(); -> SALIDAS con números aleatorios (**LOS NÚMEROS SON IDS DE PRODUCTOS**): 4,3 - 3,4,5 - 1,5,4`

Quiero pasar esos datos a tres arreglos INT en Java, intento esto y no funciona:

```
String cosa1 = request.getParameter("cosa1").toString();
String cosa2 = request.getParameter("cosa2").toString();
String cosa3 = request.getParameter("cosa3").toString();
int cosa_1 = Integer.parseInt("cosa1");
int cosa_2 = Integer.parseInt("cosa2");
int cosa_3 = Integer.parseInt("cosa3");
```

Me envia una el siguiente error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP /registro/18-paso-23.jsp en línea 35

32:             String cosa1 = request.getParameter("cosa1").toString();
33:             String cosa2 = request.getParameter("cosa2").toString();
34:             String cosa3 = request.getParameter("cosa3").toString();
35:             int cosa_1 = Integer.parseInt("cosa1");
36:             int cosa_2 = Integer.parseInt("cosa2");
37:             int cosa_3 = Integer.parseInt("cosa3");
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, ya lo intente y no logro obtener mi array de enteros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la cadena tiene valores incorrectos *como la ,* para hacer el `cast` seguro obtendrá un `NumberFormatException` como parece ser su caso.

Para convertir a `array` de enteros pueden haber muchas formas pero mostraré dos, de forma iterativa y con `Streams` *(deberá sustituir la variable a en por cosa1 , cosa2, etc) además con la expresión regular evitamos espacios, letras.*

```
String a = "1,2,3,4,7,a,7,, ,,";
String[] digitos =  a.split("\\D+"); //
int[] resultado = new int[digitos.length];
for (int i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
    resultado[i] = Integer.parseInt(digitos[i].trim());
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultado));
```

**Salida**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 7]
```

**Streams**

```
int[] resultado= Stream.of(a.split("\\D+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultado));
```

Comment: Gracias Dev. Joel, aprecio tu ayuda!